# Creating a for loop in Python for multiple instances in Abaqus

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, instance, abaqus

I am new to coding in Python for Abaqus, and I am trying to create a for loop, where I can create X number of instances based on a part, I have made. Furthermore, I would like to update the naming of the X instances.

Currently, when I manually create four instances based on the part CenMid, the code looks like this

```
mdb.models[panelName].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name='CenMid-1', 
    part=mdb.models[panelName].parts['CenMid'])
mdb.models[panelName].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name='CenMid-2', 
    part=mdb.models[panelName].parts['CenMid'])
mdb.models[panelName].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name='CenMid-3', 
    part=mdb.models[panelName].parts['CenMid'])
mdb.models[panelName].rootAssembly.Instance(dependent=ON, name='CenMid-4', 
    part=mdb.models[panelName].parts['CenMid'])
```

This is the code, I would like to transform to a loop, so that I simply can choose X instances and X instances will be created with the respective name, instead of this "hard coding" solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here's a control flow tutorial, it covers for and while loops: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Thank you for that, however my concern is more regarding how I implement the showed code as a function, where the number of instances and the name of it is changed?

Comment: Look also for the built-in `range` method (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) and methods for the string formatting (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Thank you. I've only managed to create the range loop (where nMz is the number of parts in the length direction). However the next part, the function itself, I am having a hard time coding.
`for n in range(1,nMz+1):`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a for loop with range und adjust the names accordingly or use the names from a list of either by for loop created names or, userdefined names.

Here is a for loop approach

```
pt_name = 'CenMid'
r_A = mdb.models[panelName].rootAssembly # root assembly
inst_basename = 'CenMid-'
inst_numbers = 5 # number of created instances plus 1

for inst_num in range(1,inst_numbers):
    i_name = inst_basename + str(inst_num) # instance name
    
    r_A.Instance(dependent=ON, name=i_name, 
    part=mdb.models[panelName].parts[pt_name])
```